# RGB Image resize in Python

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, resize, interpolation

I have problems with manipulating an RGB image using Python and TensorFlow. I want to interpolate an RGB image using bicubic interpolation. In Matlab I can do that using a `for` loop as follows:

```
for i= 1:3
  im1(:,:,i)= imresize(im(:,:,i), [256 256], 'bicubic');
end
```

But how can I do that in Python? I have tried using the following command, but it gives me an error.

```
im1 = tf.image.resize_images(im, [256, 256, 3], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BICUBIC)
```

Comment: What's `im`? TF function is designed to work with tensors

Comment: im is the original RGB image which I want to resize to (256,256)

Comment: There is a difference if it's a tensor or numpy array